# cross-compile with clang using mingw on linux

Tags: linux, windows, mingw, clang, cross-compiling

I was trying to compile under linux for windows. I have installed binutils multilib for linux and w64-mingw.
If I compile with x86_64-w64-mingw-gcc everything work, but if I use clang with -target x86_64-w64-mingw or x86_64-windows-gnu compiler give me lots of warnings and a include error for windows.h.

What is the problem? Clang does not support mingw binutils?

P.S. I also are interested in cross-compilig for freebsd, where can I found binutils for targeting freebsd?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 8):

`-target` isn't enough, you also need to specify the include directories,
i.e.:

```
clang -target i686-w64-mingw32 -nostdinc -fno-exceptions -isystem /opt/compiler/llvm-3.6/bin/../lib/clang/3.6.0/include -isystem /opt/compiler/mingw-w64/i686-w64-mingw32/include -isystem /opt/compiler/mingw-w64/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/4.9.2 -isystem /opt/compiler/mingw-w64/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/4.9.2/backward -isystem /opt/compiler/mingw-w64/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/4.9.2/i686-w64-mingw32
```

You may find my project useful: https://github.com/tpoechtrager/wclang -
that tool is doing all the nasty include directory searching for you.

Comment: Yes, I tried your project and it's very useful, but I would like to learn how to do this also for other archs.
However I tried:
`clang -target i686-w64-mingw32 -nostdinc -fno-exceptions -isystem /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/../lib/clang/3.5.0/include -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++ -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++/backward -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32 *.c lib/*.c -otest`
and  now with -nostdinc it can't found stdio.h

Comment: Run `w32-clang -wc-verbose dummy.c` / `w64-clang -wc-verbose dummy.c` to see the include paths.

Answer (score 1):

My [ELLCC](http://ellcc.org) project packages clang with libraries and include files that can target multiple targets, including various Linux targets and Windows using MinGW-64 includes and libraries. I have a slightly modified version of clang, which I call **ecc**, that supports configuration files to specify where to get include files, how to link, etc. A typical config file for clang/mingw looks like [this](http://ellcc.org/viewvc/svn/ellcc/trunk/libecc/config/x86_64-w64-mingw32?view=markup). I've modified clang's -target option to check for an applicable config file and use it if it exists.For example, to target 64 bit Windows, you use the command line

```
ecc -target x86_64-w64-mingw32 hello.c
```

To compile the same program for e.g. an ARM Linux system, you can use a command line like

```
ecc -target arm-linux-engeabihf hello.c
```

A complete list of the supported targets is [available here](http://ellcc.org/blog/?page_id=313). Pre-compiled binary packages for various Linux hosts and Windows are [available](http://ellcc.org/blog/?page_id=20295). The packages include binutils and GDB that support all the targets.